# Frequent operation of database with spring boot mess the data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In Spring Data JPA, I update my entity with the method that delete the old entity then save a new one. Like this:

```
iconRepository.delete(icon);
iconRepository.save(newIcon);
```

The entity icon has a property `position`. It is a coordinate. And the frontend will change this position by drag the element. Drag event will be triggered many time during a very short period of time. It will cause that the old icon has not been deleted but the new one has been saved. How can I deal with this situation?

*English isn't my native language, if I make a spelling error, don't hesitate to let me know it.*

Comment: its not possible to just overwrite the icon with the same ID?

Comment: Yes, so sometimes it will throw error about duplicate Id.

Comment: you should get your old icon and change the values of the icon. Leave the id as it is and save the icon again. It should just overwrite the values and not save another icon

Comment: Do you have a transaction that covers both delete and save or are these separate transactions?

Comment: As Patrick mentioned, you should update your entity. But in these cases, you probably also want to debounce these calls on the frontend. If a user moves the icon from `0,0` to `100,100` in a second, there's no reason to update the icon from `0,0` to `1,1`, `2,2`, `3,3`, ... . No clue what frontend framework you're using to make the calls, but you should look into debouncing those calls.

Comment: If two entities have the same id, `iconRepository.save(newIcon);` will update entity. I needn't delete the old one then add new one. The problem has been resolved and thank you for the help.